# css image replacement: why the kellum method doesn't work with button elements?

Tags: html, css, image-replacement

I've found out that the kellum method doesn't really work with html button elements. More precisely, it works but need more text indent. To recap, this is the techniqhe:

```
text-indent: 100%;
white-space: nowrap;
overflow: hidden;
```

With button elems, I've got to text-indent more, say 200%, it depends, it seems not to have a specific rule, but surely more than 100%. Why?

Comment: Sorry, its unclear to me.

Comment: Are you trying to hide the text and show the image? If yes, you can also use the `font-size: 0;`

Comment: Good question I always wondered why 100% didn't cover all elements - I started using 150% just to be sure

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some elements like `button` have an intrinsic padding.

Remove that, and you will get consistent results. Also, use a reset css whenever possible to provide you with a clean slate to start your styling with. Proper `box-sizing` is also important.

This is the reason, people generally play safe and use an indent of far more than 100%.

***Check this snippet:*** (*Try removing padding from `*`*)

```css
* {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    margin: 0; padding: 0;
}
button, span {
    width: 120px;
    height: 32px;
    text-indent: 100%;
    white-space: nowrap;
    overflow: hidden;
    display: inline-block;
    border: 1px solid gray;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

```html
<button>Button</button>
<span>Span</span>
```

Comment: Hi, thank you, I can see  a piece of B running the snippet :)

Comment: P.s. I'm on latest firefox. I see that in chrome it works properly.

Comment: @Stratboy: Yes. That's why a proper css reset is so important these days. It helps mitigate browser inconsistencies to a large extent. However, on elements like button, you have to take the padding in account and increase the indent by that proportion.